# How to automatically download JDK with existing project?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jvm

Is there a way to write instructions in Gradle files(or some other way) to download JDK if a person who opens a specific existing Gradle project in IntelliJ IDEA has no downloaded JDK at all? The aim I'm pursuing is if person has only IntelliJ IDEA on the computer, the only thing he will need to do to build a project - to open it.

Comment: You'd still need some form of jre or jdk to run gradle, wouldn't you. So that would still not work across all platforms

Comment: Gradle goes with IDE or that's not what you are saying?

Comment: And how do you run IntelliJ IDEA without a Java installation?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking, if there a way to automatically install Java when a person opens a project locally in IDEA(probably not but maybe there is a way)

Comment: You don’t get to open a project without Java as without Java, a Java application like IntelliJ IDEA won’t even start. But don’t worry, Java is included in IntelliJ’s ordinary download bundles. So you can run it, open a project and be sure that there is a Java installation.